# Why AMD64 RSP register was subtracted 8 bytes wrongly?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86-64

Now I met one issue about kernel panic at linux-3.0, it seems RSP register was subtracted 8 bytes wrongly. So I can not Judge it is a CPU bug or kernel bug. But I go through the assemble code of do page_fault, no find any code to -8 for rsp.hope you can give me some ideas. Thanks!

BTW:This issue is hard to be reproduced, and only met in one x86 machine.

(1) For AMD64, r12-r15 and rbx, rbp are callee save registers, when call do_page_fault, in this function, they will be saved.
The stack like below:

```
00007f48c91c1000(r11)
0000000000000000(rbx)
00007ffc0f907bb0(rbp)
00007f48c9558000(r12)
00007f48c91c9708(r13)
00007f48ca168500(r14) 
00007f48ca168500(r15)(caller save)
ffffffff81461fc5(page_fault+0x25/0x30)* (return address)
00007f48ca168500(r15) (callee save)
00007f48ca168500(r14) 
00007f48c91c9708(r13)
00007f48c9558000(r12)
00007ffc0f907bb0(rbp) 
00007f48c91e8598(rbx)
```

(2) But I got one wrong return value when do_page_fault finished, it should pop “page_fault+0x25/0x30” to RIP, but it seems pop the “00007f48ca168500(r15)” to RIP and cause this following OOP, it seems RSP register was subtracted 8 bytes wrongly in do_page_fault function:

```
<6>[29205.617769] ovs-vsctl[33927]: segfault at 7f48c9558000 ip 00007f48c9f62285 sp 00007ffc0f907ad0 error 6 in ld-2.11.3.so[7f48c9f57000+1f000]
<1>[29205.617808] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 00007f48ca168500
<1>[29205.621539] IP: [<00007f48ca168500>] 0x7f48ca1684ff
<4>[29205.621539] PGD 3f76860067 PUD 32cf7f7067 PMD 2afce53067 PTE 800000375422e067
<1>[29205.621539] Thread overran stack, or stack corrupted
<0>[29205.621539] Oops: 0011 [#1] SMP 
<4>[29205.621539] Inexact backtrace:
<4>[29205.621539] 
<4>[29205.621539] CPU 43 
<4>[29205.621539] Supported: No, Unsupported modules are loaded
<4>[29205.621539] 
<4>[29205.621539] Pid: 33927, comm: ovs-vsctl Tainted: GF NX 3.0.93-0.8-default #1 xxxxx
<4>[29205.621539] RIP: 0010:[<00007f48ca168500>] [<00007f48ca168500>] 0x7f48ca1684ff
<4>[29205.621539] RSP: 0000:ffff882b370adf50 EFLAGS: 00010286
<4>[29205.621539] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 00007f48c91c0000 RCX: ffff883fb99c03c0
<4>[29205.621539] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000286 RDI: 0000000000000286
<4>[29205.621539] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000020 R09: 0000000000000000
<4>[29205.621539] R10: 0000000000000006 R11: 000000000000004a R12: 00007ffc0f907bb0
<4>[29205.621539] R13: 00007f48c9558000 R14: 00007f48c91c9708 R15: 00007f48ca168500
<4>[29205.621539] FS: 00007f48ca163c00(0000) GS:ffff88407f3e0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
<4>[29205.621539] CS: 0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
<4>[29205.621539] CR2: 00007f48ca168500 CR3: 0000002b3ce96000 CR4: 00000000001427e0
<4>[29205.621539] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
<4>[29205.621539] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
<4>[29205.621539] Process ovs-vsctl (pid: 33927, threadinfo ffff882b370ac000, task ffff883fb99c03c0)
<0>[29205.621539] Stack:
<4>[29205.621539] ffffffff81461fc5 00007f48ca168500(r15) 00007f48ca168500(r14) 00007f48c91c9708(r13)
<4>[29205.621539] 00007f48c9558000(r12) 00007ffc0f907bb0(rbp) 00007f48c91e8598(rbx) 00007f48c91c1000(r11)
<4>[29205.621539] 00007f48c955ed60(r10) 0000000000000001(r9) 00007f48c91c5cb8(r8) 0000000000000007
<0>[29205.621539] Call Trace:
<0>[29205.621539] Inexact backtrace:
<0>[29205.621539] 
<4>[29205.621539] [<ffffffff81461fc5>] ? page_fault+0x25/0x30
<0>[29205.621539] Code: Bad RIP value.
<1>[29205.621539] RIP [<00007f48ca168500>] 0x7f48ca1684ff
<4>[29205.621539] RSP <ffff882b370adf50>
<0>[29205.621539] CR2: 00007f48ca168500
```

Page_fault call sequence:

```
ffffffff81461fa0 <page_fault>:
ffffffff81461fa0:       ff 15 ca aa 5b 00       callq  *0x5baaca(%rip)        # ffff:
ffff81a1ca70 <pv_irq_ops+0x30>
ffffffff81461fa6:       48 83 ec 78             sub    $0x78,%rsp
ffffffff81461faa:       e8 b1 01 00 00          callq  ffffffff81462160 <error_entry>
ffffffff81461faf:       48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
ffffffff81461fb2:       48 8b 74 24 78          mov    0x78(%rsp),%rsi
ffffffff81461fb7:       48 c7 44 24 78 ff ff    movq   $0xffffffffffffffff,0x78(%rsp)
ffffffff81461fbe:       ff ff
ffffffff81461fc0:       e8 6b 32 00 00          callq  ffffffff81465230 <do_page_fault>
ffffffff81461fc5:       e9 46 02 00 00          jmpq   ffffffff81462210 <error_exit>  ffffffff81461fc5(page_fault+0x25/0x30)
ffffffff81461fca:       66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

Comment: Sounds like there's a buffer overflow somewhere. The subtraction you mentioned could just be to align the stack to a 16-byte boundary which is mandated by some ABIs.

Comment: If buffer overflow, it should corrupt existing stack contents, but here, at least, callee save's r12-r15 values are right. As for 16bytes align, it should compiler taking the management? I dump the assembly code, it should be aligned normally.